# Debugging Oracle queries being sent by Oracle

Tags: php, oracle

I have a large PHP program that interacts with an Oracle DB.  There are obviously view pages and pages that are more for program logic.  Some of my logical pages need to be debugged.

I have Oracle queries being executed from some of these pages.  How can you see what queries are being sent to Oracle?  Printing queries from these types of pages doesn't seem to work i.e. nothing is printed.  Is there some sort of Oracle log file that I can look at?

Thanks very much :).

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on tracing for the session and look at the trace files created in the database's `user_dump_dest` directory, assuming you have access to the database server and permission to view those. There's an overview of the deprecated [sqltrace](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_Trace) method, and the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams205.htm#REFRN10208) for that; and the newer [DBMS_MONITOR](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_monitor.htm).

I'd start by looking at the [application tracing tools](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/sqltrace.htm#i4170) Oracle provide.